# In Unity, how can I save a list of gameobjects, including their state and make them persist into the next scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.2.0f3 for a current project that puts the player into a management role for a simulated factory. The player is given the option to hire additional workers during the game to speed up production. The player also has the option to choose a different floor layout (Unity scenes). The trouble I'm having is that all of the additional workers are destroyed each time a different layout is loaded, due to the scene change.

I've tried adding DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject) to the Start() function with no benefit. I've been scratching my head for a while now so I appreciate all your help with this.

EDIT: Forgot to add relevant code..

I have two scripts. HiringManager.cs to instantiate additional workers, and is attached to an empty gameobject, and WorkerAI.cs which is attached to each worker gameobject and handles worker behaviour.

Code to instantiate additional workers (HiringManager):

```
public void HireWorker(string name) {
    _worker = Instantiate (worker) as GameObject;
    _worker.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Workers").transform;
    _worker.transform.position = new Vector2(-100f, -100f);
    _worker.name = name;
    _worker.tag = "New Worker";

    _workerAI = _worker.GetComponent<NWorker.WorkerAI>();
    _workerAI.isDragging = true;
}
```

And code that I've tried (WorkerAI):

```
void Start()
    if (CompareTag("New Worker")) {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do this by coding it for starters.. and on a serious note if you are having issues with your code.. how can anyone know what you are doing when they can't see the code that you are seeing.. also learn to use the tools that are at your disposal for example the debugger.. step through your code and try to pinpoint where the breakdown is happening..

Comment: Pretty basic, but I added relevant code to my question. Also the only Unity debugger I'm aware of that won't help in this situation is the frame debugger. What I'm missing or what exactly I'm doing wrong I'm unsure of. That's my problem.

Comment: There is the Visual Studio debugger, or whatever other program you're using to write your C# code in. There's something that Unity has by default, but I don't remember what it is off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ for script editing, but I can try the VS debugger to see if it can tell me something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out my code was fine... for the most part. In the code segment for instantiating additional workers you can see this line:

```
_worker.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Workers").transform;
```

Here all I'm doing is setting the parent transform for the new worker gameobject, which also is the same parent for the existing workers as well. I commented out this line and my worker remained in the hierarchy when the scene changed.

What I believe happened, and correct me if I'm incorrect here, was due to the gameobject's parent being destroyed, which caused this and all other worker gameobjects to be destroyed as well.